# How can I make dir command in cmd.exe to behave as though it were under a different Locale?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, language, locale

When I change my System Locale to a Simplified Chinese (PRC), and I open cmd.exe, a `dir` command will display the Chinese character file names correctly.

If my System Locale is English (United States), a `dir` will screw up the Chinese characters.

**How can I make the `dir` display Chinese characters correctly under the English locale?**

I've looked at related questions to displaying Chinese characters in cmd.exe but none of them make note of the fact that it works perfectly fine the Simplified Chinese locale.

Comment: Does the `chcp 65001` command help?

Comment: Not really. It changes the code pages without changing the available fonts. I've also tried various hacks for changing the fonts directly but those did not pan out either.

Comment: In addition to the chcp command try setting Lucida Console as the font for the command prompt window from its properties.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that combination as well, and the Chinese characters in the file names still come out as boxes when I run the `dir` command. I think it is not just specific to cmd.exe but specific to the command `dir` itself, and its behavior under different locales.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 folders (One in Chinese, One in Japanese):

- 你好
- こんにちは

In Command Prompt, when displaying the folder using dir, the font become question mark with box. To the system, it is still the correct characters.

[Click here to see the folder displayed in Consolas font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Otc.png)

But, if you were to display the font in NSimSun font or SimSun-ExtB, it can display correctly.

[See here on NSimSun font and SimSun-ExtB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5S02.png)

You can change the font at the Command Prompt Properties by Right-Click the App Bar.

I am using Windows 10 with AU, but I believe the previous version of Windows should work if you just change the font.